# Draggable div on top of entire page (on page load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, z-axis

I am working on a web project that should include a draggable element, which I placed in the page using `javascript` and `jquery`.

Everything is working as intended, but the div which is draggable takes up some space between the `div` above and below it. I would like this draggable element to be on top of the rest of the page right after loading the page, i.e. I would like it to not take up space between the `div` above and the `div` below but to be generated on top of everything. See the video and jsfiddle below.

How might I be able to accomplish this?

[image: Draggable_Cat]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eboL8j1n/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;` like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable().css("position", "absolute");;
});
```

Updated [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eboL8j1n/3/).

Also, In your CSS, you were using the wrong selector type. In your HTML you had the id `draggable` and in your CSS you were using it as a class.

Change your CSS as given below:

```
.draggable { 
    z-index: 4000;
    width: 350px; 
    height: 350px; 
    padding: 0em;
}
```

with this:

```
#draggable { 
    z-index: 4000;
    width: 350px; 
    height: 350px; 
    padding: 0em;
}
```